# No rule to make target `–f'

Tags: linux, makefile, terminal, remote-server

I am trying to make a c file like

```
make –f makefile1
```

This is my make file:

```
TestAssn1: test_assign1_1.o dberror.o storage_mgr.o
        cc -o TestAssn1 test_assign1_1.o dberror.o storage_mgr.o
test_assign1_1.o: test_assign1_1.c test_helper.h dberror.h storage_mgr.h
        cc -c test_assign1_1.c
dberror.o: dberror.c dberror.h
        cc -c dberror.c
storage_mgr.o: storage_mgr.c storage_mgr.h dberror.h
        cc -c storage_mgr.c
```

But I only get this message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `–f'.  Stop.
```

How should I correct this?

Comment: Is there an alias or function called `make` in your shell's environment.  You have to be trying rather hard to get that error.  In fact, I'm not sure how you do it.  My nearest approach is typing `make -f -f` which yields two lines of output:
``make: -f: No such file or directory`` and 
``make: *** No rule to make target `-f'.  Stop.``

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a normal dash (`-`), not an [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash), in the command.

My guess is you copied this command from a blog or other web source. Many blog/web frameworks have a bug where they will replace typewriter punctuation with their typographically correct counterparts *even within code formatted text*.

Answer (score 0):

This is very odd as your make usage is correct per http://linux.die.net/man/1/make

Please try some of the other formats for this option:

```
-f file, --file=file, --makefile=FILE  
    Use file as a makefile.
```

Otherwise, perhaps your `make` is not the one listed in that man page (which is GNU `make`).